# Get GMAIL message ID with php-imap library

Tags: php, gmail, imap, php-imap

I catch trouble with getting gmail message id **without** using API (standard php-imap library with login/password authorization). I found info about X-GM-THRID flag, but how can i use it with standard functions from this http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.imap.php lib??

I want to get this ID https://yadi.sk/i/lF_9rRMZps3n5

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge to php-imap there is no native ID this that exist on GMAIL.
So probably it's generated on client side based on email id and user id and some random numbers

Comment: it's constant 100% (it's not change by reload or any actions in client-side UI). but any ideas to generate it, mb from official library? realy? no one get this problem yet???

Comment: never seen something like this while working with php and imap